Quad Precision Version of DSYEVD Routine in Fortran Compilers
I am currently working on a project that requires computing all eigenvalues and, optionally, eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix with very high precision. I have been using the DSYEVD routine.
However, my project now demands quad precision computations. I am aware that DSYEVD is part of the LAPACK library and typically available in Fortran compilers, but I haven't been able to find a quad precision version of this routine.

Does Intel provide a quad precision version of the DSYEVD routine or any equivalent routine for this purpose?
If not, do other Fortran compilers like nvfortran or NAG Fortran have a quad precision version of this routine, or any equivalent routine that I could use?


It's very late after your question, but you may have a look to the Fortran "Standard" Library, which is a community driven project. They have recently released the linalg module, which includes a modernized version of Lapack and wrapper functions. And quadruple precision is natively available.
